# Adding a javascript to all pages in OpenCart

Tags: php, javascript, opencart

I'm new to OpenCart and don't have any experience with PHP, so I have a question. I want to add the following JavaScript to hide the url bar on mobile browsers

```
// When ready...
 window.addEventListener("load",function() {
 // Set a timeout...
 setTimeout(function(){
 // Hide the address bar!
 window.scrollTo(0, 1);
 }, 0);
});
```

However, I can't find a way to insert this so this code will be executed on all pages in OpenCart. Where should I put this code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

save your script to a file, say 'catalog/view/javascript/myscript.js'

Then add

```
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/myscript.js');
```

to the **catalog/controller/common/header.php** some place before this line:

```
$this->data['scripts'] = $this->document->getScripts();
```

You could also just place your script inline into **catalog/view/theme/{theme name}/template/common/header.tpl** using normal html markup.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [theme documentation](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=documentation/documentation&path=77_43_44), I believe you want to edit the following file:

```
catalog/view/theme/{your-theme}/template/common/header.tpl
```

These templates (header, footer, etc) should appear on all pages.

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't work. I pasted the JavaScript in <script type="text/javascript">...</script> right before it says

`<?php foreach ($scripts as $script) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $script; ?>"></script>
<?php } ?>`

Comment: You could try adding `<?php var_dump(get_included_files()); ?>` to the very bottom of your main index.php file (the one loaded first by your web server, likely in your document root). This should show you what files OpenCart is loading and help you track the correct one down.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go through this trouble especially if you don't have access to FTP. All you need to do is just go to admin panel > design > theme editor > and choose the respective parts to insert the codes. If is footer then just choose footer.twig.

After adding the codes, click Save and you will see the changes immediately. If add the codes directly to the file on FTP, it won't work.

Tried and tested on OpenCart 3

Comment: It is not true that after installing the script into a file and uploading via ftp is not working. After you make some changes you always must refresh modifications and clear cache in admin and all working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To add a script like that, just go to admin panel > design > theme editor > select "common" > footer and in the end of the file (after `</html>`) add the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want script to all your pages of the OC just add it before footer tag in footer.tpl or footer.twig