# Add a JS and CSS code to Opencart header

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart

I want to add the following CSS code to the header in Opencart:

```
/*=======================================================
MBL Page Peel PRO Effect For Blogger
=======================================================*/
.admin-bar #PagePeel{top:27px;}
/*Extra 20px height and width to allow for shadow and movement*/
#PagePeel{
height:120px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
width:120px;
z-index:9999;
}
#PagePeel svg{
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute !important;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
#PagePeel .pointCursor:hover{cursor:pointer;}
#mycontent { position:relative; margin-left:30px; }
```

and also then the following code to the global body file in Opencart:

```
<!--MBL Page Peel PRO Effect For Blogger-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B0WJjcJEFNziazIzXzlhMlhtWlU'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B0WJjcJEFNziMmk4anpFWnRPWHc'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B0WJjcJEFNzidExmT1JpWV9xNmc'></script>
<div id="mycontent">Peel Away Effect By <a href="http://www.mybloggerlab.com">MyBloggerLab.com</a></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var PagePeelProParams = {"smallImageUrl":"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-8R2exm5kGEs/UP1mU6NRXaI/AAAAAAAAMNw/ale8VHoC3Aw/s1600/DottedAdvertSmall.png","largeImageUrl":"http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_8kUOwvbkak/UP1kHs-ODwI/AAAAAAAAMNg/04l7M_kMZAE/s1600/Temppeel.png","peelColorStart":"#545454","peelColorEnd":"#cdcdcf","pagePeelTargetUrl":"http://www.templateism.com","pagePeelActivateEvent":"hover"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

So how can I do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add javascript and Css in `header.tpl`.

you can also refer below solutions:-

[Adding a javascript to all pages in OpenCart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787378/adding-a-javascript-to-all-pages-in-opencart)

Comment: yes you can. But I would suggest to you call this JS in header and Add piece of Css in any common css. We should avoid writing inline css in our page.

Comment: ok i will add the JS to header but where to add the css please? can you give the filename for css?

Comment: friend...here is please check it...i added both the css and JS to header.tpl and now the peel away effect is showing great on the homepage mean index page of open cart but shows no image when someone open another link...can you check it please...

Comment: I think it may be `stylesheet/stylesheet.css` inside your theme folder. Or you can check in your view source which is your common loaded css.

Comment: friend...i added it it is still like that...! i mean can you check the link as : http://www.nzonesies.co.nz/ and now check this : http://www.nzonesies.co.nz/index.php so in first link without index.php it works perfectly but in the link with index.php or any other url inside the main domain it doesn't work..so can you please point out why it is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Include Css file code:

```
$this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/theme/themename/stylesheet/product.css');
```

Include Js file code:

```
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/theme/themename/js/product.js');
```

Source: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2017/02/how-to-add-css-and-js-file-in-head.html